# Laravel route resource Not Found From my Domain Get Url

Tags: php, laravel-5

My Route Resource find in my localhost. But when I upload my app in cpanel it couldn't find .

Route File ::

```
Route::get('/' , function() {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('notes','NoteController');
```

My localhost whe the url like as -

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/notes
```

It works nice. But in my hosting or Cpanel upload

```
http://api.somrat.info/
```

It works fine , But when type url -

```
http://api.somrat.info/notes
```

It's product 404 error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the problem is actually in your server setting. I think, if you access your url like this: http://api.somrat.info/index.php/notes, you'll get the output.

So, if you get the page without 404 error, then check your `public/.htaccess` file. Check if the `RewriteRule` is written for handling `index.php`.

If `.htaccess` file is okay, then maybe you need to enable `mod_rewrite` in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Find public directory inside your project, copy all files "index.php, .htaccess" and folders inside it, then Paste the files inside http directory.
Open index.php and modify this two lines:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

To

```
require __DIR__.'/../yourProjectName/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../yourProjectName/bootstrap/app.php';
```

That's a complete tutorial for setting up laravel on Cpanel:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/easiest-way-setting-up-laravel-5-cpanel-omar-sabry?trk=mp-author-card